# Yii2 kartik Select2 validation

Tags: yii2

Steps to reproduce the issue

This bug is select2 tag
1.Select the dropdown value
2.Insert new tag value

Now validation will not work

If doing like in this order validation is working
1.Insert new tag value
2.Select the dropdown value
Expected behavior and actual behavior

When one attribute has validation rules its not working.
Ex: If one field have validation rule of email

It is working when tag is inserting at first (Without selected dropdown See image 1)
[image]

When any of dropdown selected then new tag value is not validating ( See image 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure that can be a bug of select2 or Kartik extension, since you are validation just email in text input, what can you do is to bind a event on `selecting` where you can prevent last selected value if it not matches your regular expression example:

```
pluginEvents = [
    "select2:selecting" => "function(evt) { 
         console.log(  evt.choice  );
         // Try validating evt.choice to a valid email address  
         // If email is not a valid email address then do evt.preventDefault()  
     }"
];
```

From [KartikSelect2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) there is a section of plugin events or if you need more info on the events then see select2 [documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [EachValidator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md#yiivalidatorseachvalidatoreach-).